# SQL para comparar horas e minutos uando Timestamp no PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Estou tentando comparar 2 campos timestamp, que possuem datas diferentes, ignorando as datas e utilizando apenas a hora/minuto de modo simultâneo, para saber, dentro de um mesmo dia qual deles é maior.

**EX: '2000-10-10 10:00:22' > '2000-02-02 11:00:10'**

Neste caso seria ignorado as datas sendo comparado apenas '10:00' > '11:00' retornando FALSO.
Tentei usar EXTRACT() mas não encontrei algo do tipo "time"
O SQL seria algo nesse estilo (**Se o *time* existisse**):

```
SELECT * FROM "Tabela" WHERE EXTRACT(TIME FROM "Coluna_1") > EXTRACT(TIME FROM "Coluna_2")
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM "Tabela" WHERE "Coluna_1"::time > "Coluna_2"::time` funciona?

Comment: Obrigado pela diga, não conhecia este modo. Queria algo que eliminasse os centésimos, mas esse deve funcionar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode aplicar um cast da data para time para comparar apenas as horas/minutos, basta usar `::` seguido do tipo.

```
SELECT * FROM "Tabela" WHERE "Coluna_1"::time > "Coluna_2"::time
```

[Exemplo - sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/14364)

Answer (score 2):

Sua abordagem está correta, exceto pelo uso de *time*. Uma alternativa é fazer o CAST to campo de TIMESTAMP para TIME, permitindo a comparação somente da hora do campo. A utilização do CAST neste caso, além de funcionar, mantém a compatibilidade com outros SGBDs (que possuam a diretiva TIME, obviamente):

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA WHERE CAST(Coluna_1 AS TIME) > CAST(Coluna_2 AS TIME)
```

[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8b0e6/2)

Comment: Esta alternativa não funcionou, pelo menos no PostgreSQL não. Aparentemente ele não permite um cast da coluna timestamp para um time. Retirando o time ele fornece o epoch do timestamp, incluindo a data.

Comment: Desculpe pelo descuido. Editei a resposta. Obrigado.